# Collectd SNMP plugin unable to find MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, collectd

Using Collectd to poll Cisco gear via the snmp plugin. I have the needed Cisco mibs (CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB and CISCO-PROCESS-MIB) loaded into net-snmp and snmpwalk can see them fine.

But when I try to add them into collectd I get the following error when restarting the collectd service:

```
Cannot find module (CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (CISCO-PROCESS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
```

the log file shows:

```
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] Exiting normally.
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] collectd: Stopping 5 read threads.
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: read_objid (CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolName) failed.
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: read_objid (CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolName) failed.
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: snmp_parse_oid (CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal5secRev) failed.
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_free'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_used'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `cisco_cpu'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_free'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_used'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `cisco_cpu'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_free'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `memory_used'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] snmp plugin: No such data configured: `cisco_cpu'
[2016-11-09 14:13:56] Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
```

Here is my snmp section of collectd.conf

```
<Plugin snmp>
  <Data "SysInfo">
      Type "counter"
      Table false
      Instance "sysName"
      Values  "SNMPv2-MIB::sysName"
  </Data>
  <Data "uptime">
     Type "uptime"
     Table false
     Instance "Uptime"
     scale 0.01
    Values  "DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance"
  </Data>
  <Data "if_octets">
      Type "if_octets"
      Table true
      Instance "IF-MIB::ifAlias"
      Values "IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets" "IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets"
  </Data>
  <Data "if_errors">
    Type "if_errors"
    Table true
    Instance "IF-MIB::ifAlias"
    Values "IF-MIB::ifInErrors" "IF-MIB::ifOutErrors"
  </Data>
 <Data "memory_free">
    Type "memory_free"
    Table true
    Instance "CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolName"
    Values  "CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolFree"
  </Data>
  <Data "memory_used">
    Type "memory_used"
    Table true
    Instance "CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolName"
    Values "CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolUsed"
  </Data>
  <Data "cisco_cpu">
      Type "cisco_cpu"
      Table true
      Values "CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal5secRev" "CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal1minRev" "CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal5minRev"
  </Data>
```

What am I missing here? Ive also tried using the OID address instead of name but I get nothing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with some settings and Im getting some success.

The CISCO-MEMORY-POOL PoolFree/Used works if I change the type to "gauge" and table to "false". Makes sense. But CISCO-PROCESS-MIB cpu returns as a percentage it looks like. Still cant get that one.

Here is how snmpwalk returns the OIDs:

```
[root@NMS-srv2 ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c rbhome spine1 CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolFree
CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolFree.1 = Gauge32: 564215448 bytes

[root@NMS-srv2 ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c rbhome spine1 CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolUsed
CISCO-MEMORY-POOL-MIB::ciscoMemoryPoolUsed.1 = Gauge32: 249119560 bytes

[root@NMS-srv2 ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c rbhome spine1 CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal1minRev
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmCPUTotal1minRev.7 = Gauge32: 1 percent
```

Here is the config right now.

```
 <Data "memory_used">
    Type "gauge"
    Table false
    Instance "memory_used"
    Values "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.5.1"
  </Data>
  <Data "cisco_cpu">
      Type "gauge"
      Table false
      Instance "cpu_used_min"
      Values "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.7.7" "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.8.7"
  </Data>
```

Still cant figure out the MIB / OID name issue.